# Is there a connection between melee damage and resource collection?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I have been told that there is a connection between melee damage, tool type and tool level when collecting resources from their sources.

Is there a known formula for the harvesting of resources in ARK?

Comment: I don't think the exact formula is known yet, but people have expirimented with the Melee Damage-stat: https://www.reddit.com/r/playark/comments/3amg8k/melee_damage_affects_player_gather_rate_and_dino/

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a connection between melee damage and resource collection.

This is especially evident with tamed dinos such as the Ankylosaurus or the Beezlebufo.

I don't have a specific formula but the relationship goes something like this:

Let's say you have a tamed dino at 100% melee damage. They also have a base attack damage value which correlates to a certain amount of gathered resources per hit. (Different resources for different dinos)

If you've leveled up melee damage to say 200%, that is now 2 times the original base attack damage and I would surmise that the resource gathering increase correlates to 2 times as well.

You will eventually hit a wall where the attack damage is >= the resource health value and 1 or 2 strikes will completely harvest it. You can't really get more than is available in any given chunk but you can increase your rate of harvesting.

*This is based off of experience/observation and may not be 100% correct.*